# Big double number up to two decimal places

Tags: java, android, numbers, double

I want to round a double value upto 2 decimal places -

```
double d = 1.13452289575668E8;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

OUTPUT: `113452289.58`

---

```
double d = 2.34568;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

OUTPUT: `2.35`

So how can I get the double number like `1.13452289575668E8` to correctly display upto 2 decimal places ?

Comment: you want the result to be like (double a = 4321.1234 -> double result = 4300)?

Comment: What is wrong with the result you have already? What result are you expecting?

Comment: well the first output is not up to 2 decimal places. `double d = 1.13452289575668E8;` should become `1.13`.

Comment: What's wrong with 1.13452289575668E8 printed as 113452289.58? Isn't that what you want to get? Note that "E8" at the end means that the number actually is 113452289.575668, it's just shifted by 8 decimal places (scientific notation).

Comment: it is displaying you correct 2 decimail points

Comment: This is correct output. What is your confusion?

Comment: as Thomas said, for example 1.13E8 means 1.13*10^8

Comment: @PankajKumar - My confusion is `double d = 1.13452289575668E8;` should become `1.13` ?

Comment: No the input value is not equivalent to 1.13..., it is equal to 113452289.57... that's the reason you are getting such input.

Comment: @VedPrakash so you are saying if you give me $113 million and I give you $1.13 these are the same so you would be happy to do that?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I will neither accept nor give until I completely know these are same or different. That's a big deal. We should know what we are up to before continuing. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is being rounded up correctly

The scientific notation `1.13452289575668E8` means 1.3 x 10<sup>8</sup> which is `113452289.5756680071353912353515625`

```
double d = 1.13452289575668E8;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(d));
```

gives

```
113452289.5756680071353912353515625
```

round to 2 decimal places is `113452289.58`

Comment: If the question is invalid, shouldn't it be closed rather than answered?

Comment: this might clarify for the `OP`...